# GWT client side logging during maven test phase

Tags: gwt, maven, maven-3, gwt-maven-plugin

I'm writing a `GWT` library and I'm trying to use GWT's `Logging` capabilities.

My maven build trigger some `GWTTestCases` that tests my library.

Is it possible to have and configure the logging output of my library ? So that I could see the logging during the `test` phase.

What I actually have, but it is not working :

The `.gwt.xml` file :

```xml
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="ALL"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
```

In java code :

```java
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("xxx.client.Fusion");
```

...

```java
logger.info("Test");
logger.finer("Test");
```

I also tried setting the `logLevel` of the `gwt-maven-plugin`.

What am I missing ?

**EDIT**

I'm putting a `logging.properties` file under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. For testing, this file only contains :

```
.level = ALL
```

Comment: Did you configure `java.util.logging`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html & http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html

Comment: No, let me take a look at your link

Comment: @ThomasBroyer where should the logging.properties files be ? Is there any other configuration needed ?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Reading GWT docs, I've see this : *Unlike java.util.logging, GWT logging is configured using .gwt.xml files*. So, I don't understand why I need to have a `logging.properties` file

Comment: Ah sorry, no idea. I actually never used java.util.logging, even less trying to make it output something during tests. I suppose you could pass the path to the file (e.g. `src/test/logging.properties`) with the `java.util.logging.config.file` system property (via `extraJvmArgs` of the `gwt:test` mojo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't achieve such thing.

When I try to pass to path to logging.properties files using `-Djava.util.logging.config.file` I get a error from GWTTestCase.

So, IMHO, this is not a good usage for `logging` in general. Therefore, this kind of usage is not recommended.

For people obstinated to do it, I should recommend to take a look at `gwt-log`.